# How to keep static IP working

Tags: networking

I found this site: [click](https://www.garron.me/en/linux/add-secondary-ip-linux.html)
First I tried to use the non-permanent way via "ip address add". But the static address I assigned would not be accessible anymore after a minute or so, and this is repeatable.
So I tried the permanent approach described there for Ubuntu. I am running "Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS", albeit a probably somewhat modified, cut-down version on a Tegra TK1 board, running a NVIDIA L4T kernel derivate.

So in /etc/network/interfaces, which before interestingly only contained 2 comment lines

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
```

and nothing else, I added:

```
auto eth1:1
iface eth1:1 inet static
address 10.0.10.55
netmask 255.255.0.0
```

(the system has only a eth1, no eth0)

Well, reboot and... there is no such IP address shown in ifconfig and I can't access it.
It lists, however, for eth1:

```
inet6 addr: fe80::214:2dff:fe2f:c150/64 Scope:Link
```

What might be wrong? (I didn't ask for a ipv6 address, where would come from now?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That guide is for adding a second IP address to an existing NIC that is already in use.

As you are just trying to set a primary static IP address, put this into `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.0.10.55
gateway <your gateway>
netmask 255.255.0.0
broadcast <your broadcast>
```

You can also add:

```
dns nameservers <your dns nameservers>
```

if it's not defined in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Be sure to restart your `networking` or `NetworkManager` service or reboot afterwards.

Comment: eth1 in my case, but that works, thanks

Comment: @sktpin Updated to reflect `eth1`. You are welcome.